# Continous Integration on Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-mobile-services, continuous-deployment

Is there any way to enable continuous integration on azure mobile services using Team Foundation (TFS) source control?

I have seen its easily done on Azure Websites and Cloud Services but i dont see an option on mobile services.

My only option is to set up a custom server ?

Comment: The same way you do it to Websites maybe you can for AMS, but I can be wrong... AMS is like a Website, for example both use Kudo to deploy to the server...

Comment: On azure on websites there is an option "Integrate source control". On AMS there is no such option.. Although i think now that even on websites its only Continous Delivery, not Continous Integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this:

[image]

and maybe you shoudl see this too:

- [Store project code in source control](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-store-scripts-source-control/)
- [Git Source Control Integration with Windows Azure Mobile
  Services](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/git-source-control-integration-with-windows-azure-mobile-services)

**Update**: your source control can be TFS and you should have your own CI Server, and when is all ok you should use a git command to push it to Azure.

Comment: I see, I have my custom source control on TFS though. 
How am i deploying from TFS ? 
Plus , the custom Integration Server is still pending  since i want to have several notifications of the build state, i need to run test etc. I suppose this cant be done on azure. 
Edit your post to answer the whole question and i mark it answered. I am going with a custom Server as i see it with custom scripts to push on this git url and deploy.
Was helpful to clarify these two links anyway

Comment: in my opinion, when your server verify the build is ok and is ready to publish, you can use a git command to push it to the Azure using the url above, the CI will not run in Azure....

Comment: Cant find the credentials for this git Repository... Any suggestions ?

Comment: you can! use the data from the public profile user+pass :)